# how to change places of two data fields/ columns in Linux

Tags: linux

Question:

I have the bellow data field

```
zzzzz: 4
afsdf: 5
sdfsd: 3
```

how do I change the places of two columns so I get e.g `4: zzzzz` using the `awk` or `sed` command? If possible please show multiple ways so I can explore further

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few:

```
awk -F": " '/:/{print $2": "$1}' file
sed 's/\(.*\): *\(.*\)/\2: \1/' file
perl -pne 's/(.+?):\s*(.*)/$2: $1/' file
paste  <(cut -f 2 -d ' ' file) <(cut -f 1 -d ' ' file | sed 's/://')
while read a b; do echo "$b: $a"; done < file | sed 's/: *$//'
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also

```
perl -ple  '$_=join ": ",reverse split /:\s*/' your_file
```

and

```
perl -aF':\s*' -ple '$_=join ": ",reverse @F' your_file
```

Comment: Better `-aF':\s'`, because “You can't use literal whitespace in the pattern.” – [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).